# Compatibility of typo3-content between version 6.1.5 and 7.6

Tags: typo3, upgrade, typo3-6.2.x, typo3-7.6.x

we are going to upgrade our typo3-instance from version 6.1.5 to 7.6. Since we need to clone the instance and afterwards upgrade it in two steps (6.1.5 -> 6.2, 6.2 -> 7.6) we wonder if it was easier to setup a clean 7.6 instance and migrate the data (templates, sites, binaries etc.) afterwards.

There are multiple instruction pages on the web describing how to upgrade to 6.2 and to 7.6 but it seems to be a really tricky process.

So I'd like to know if the t3d data is compatible between those versions. Can we export the data from 6.1.5 and import it to 7.6 without troubles?

What do you think of the approach?

Thanks,
Thomas

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> So I'd like to know if the t3d data is compatible between those versions. Can we export the data from 6.1.5 and import it to 7.6 without troubles?

Most likely this process will not go without troubles.

Best advice I can give, is to upgrade to 6.2, do the upgrade wizards in the install tool. After that upgrade to 7.6 and do the upgrade wizards in the install tool again (those will be different ones).

Your content should now be fine.

You can keep incompatible extensions uninstalled during this process as it is merely targeting content migration. Don't bother with extension code while doing this. Just the core and your content is enough to provide a working content structure for 7 LTS. Migrate the extensions afterwards.

Comment: Ty for your answer! I think I'll go with the upgrade approach. The reason for my doubts were posts describing manual adjustments after the upgrade like removing folders, reconfiguring symlinks on the machine etc (especially the upgrade 6.1.5 to 6.2). Since there will probably be troubles and manual steps either way I'll follow your suggestion.

Comment: Sry but since this is my second account I cannot yet upvote your answer :(

Answer (score 3):

I prefer the upgrade way to do it, because the t3d export / import thing may work, but may cause some troubles too, especially if this is a bigger site.

If you update the extensions on your 6.2 site to current versions, fix the namespaces and deprecation log entries in your individual extensions, the 6.2. => 7.6 upgrade should be quite smooth. In my experience it is much more convenient than a 4.5 => 6.2 upgrade.

Comment: Ty for your answer! I think I'll use the upgrade approach. Since the problems of export / import will not be the only problems (we have a few other customizations) it will most likely outweigh the problems occuring when updating to 6.2.

Sry but since this is my second account I cannot yet upvote your answer :(

Comment: NP, you can do it tomorrow ;-)